# Vocabulary Question: Stane (verb); to stane to do something

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I came across the word "stane" in a poem in the *Paris Review*, and I can't seem to find a definition that fits its use in the poem. I checked several dictionaries. Some didn't have it at all, and those that did defined it as another form of the word "stone." In the poem and in the few other instances I saw it used in search results, it was used in the wider structure "to stane to do something."

Here is the quote from the poem:

> "There’s butchered meat on the bottom —
> and ice that’s staning to melt through the shop window."

And here's another quote:

> "But as the Nineties beckoned, the freewheeling attitude which makes Griffin such a refreshing interview was staning to look extremely out of time."

And another:

> "Today, by contrast, some large companies are staning to see the development of women employees as 'a business imperative.'"

Thanks very much for any help you can provide on this elusive word!

Comment: I'm guessing that it's a transcription error for "starting"

Comment: Yes, mostly likely a typo for starting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about a typical OCR error *(**staning*** for ***starting**)*.

Comment: That's fair. I found the post on the Paris Review's Facebook page and asked them about it. If I hear anything new that might contribute to this post, I'll add a comment here. Thanks!

Comment: Could it also be "stane" as another version of "stand"? "stand" is typically pronounced / stænd /  [IPA].  People say "stand" as in "I stand up for something" or "I stand with something" --> meaning "I agree with something." And so in some dialects of American English, this gets shortened to / stæn /, so that people might say "I could stan a cup o' joe [coffee]" or "I stan to think it'll be getting mighty stormy out".

Comment: @wanderling I really don't think *stand* would make sense here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Where has your CV gone? Mine added.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about a typical OCR error (staning for starting). It's worrying that FumbleFingers' CV has been magicked away.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I believe that close votes cease to have any effect after a certain number of weeks (or perhaps months)—and FumbleFingers cast his close vote on March 14, 2019. As I understand the close-voting rules at this site, if you cast a close vote that is not successful, you are barred from subsequent close voting on the same question; if that is the case, FF may not be in a position to vote to close this question. I am eligible to close-vote, however, and have done so—now that it is clear that the OP's question involves a misreading of the actual texts cited.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm pretty sure Sven is right about my CV "expiring", but not sure about me not being able to re-vote again later. I'm not going to "proceed", but I have just checked that I am able to start the process of *re-voting to re-open*. I doubt the techies would get too involved in *What **kind** of votes can be re-cast after a CV?*, so my guess is I *would* have been able to re-vote to close (possibly after some additional "cooling-off period" from my initial vote had "expired").

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [link to a snippet view](https://books.google.com/books?id=d_6wAAAAIAAJ&q=%22There%E2%80%99s+butchered+meat+on+the+bottom+%E2%80%94+and+ice+that%E2%80%99s+starting+to+melt+through+the+shop+window.%22&dq=%22There%E2%80%99s+butchered+meat+on+the+bottom+%E2%80%94+and+ice+that%E2%80%99s+starting+to+melt+through+the+shop+window.%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJ8ZPA0tfrAhVjGjQIHepHBusQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg) of the relevant phrase from the cited poem in *The Paris Review* (1993). As you can see the word in question is *starting*, not *staning*:

> There's butchered meat on the bottom— / and ice that's **starting** to melt through the shop window.

And here is a [link to a snippet view](https://books.google.com/books?id=wz4UAQAAIAAJ&q=%22was+starting+to+look+extremely+out+of+time%22&dq=%22was+starting+to+look+extremely+out+of+time%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCxdy21NfrAhX-IzQIHRXLDMAQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg) of part of the cited quotation from Brian Hinton, *Country Roads: How Country Came to Nashville* (2000) The complete sentence from that book, which happens to break across two pages, looks like this:

> But as the Nineties beckoned, the freewheeling attitude which makes Griffin such a refreshing interview was **starting** to look extremely out of time.

And finally, [here is a link to the page](https://books.google.com/books?id=cZEuAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA274&dq=%22some+large+companies+are+starting+to+see+the+development+of+women%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjelsS_1dfrAhUIJzQIHRGHAJ8Q6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22some%20large%20companies%20are%20starting%20to%20see%20the%20development%20of%20women%22&f=false) containing the cited sentence in Sonia Carreon, ‎Amy Cassedy & ‎Kathryn Borman, *Women and Work: A Handbook* (2013). The sentence reads as follows:

> Today, by contrast, some large companies are **starting** to see the development of women employees as “a business imperative” (Trost 1989).

As you can see, commenters user888379 and Lambie have correctly diagnosed the problem: the poster either repeatedly misread the 'rt' in *starting* as an 'n' or encountered multiple electronic transcriptions of the original texts that introduced the erroneous spelling as a result of faulty optical character recognition.

Comment: How is this on-topic?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The question has been open since March 2019 and was occupying a rather prominent place in the unanswered questions queue (it was on the first or second page of the queue, with three upvotes, at the time I answered it). I don't object to its being closed or even deleted, if you and others feel strongly that it should be. In the meantime, I have substantiated the surmise of some early commenters that the texts in question do not contain examples of a word spelled _staning_. I have no regrets about having done so.